# Why isn't blender exporting colors to .mtl?

Tags: materials, export

I had create a dice model and added two materials to it: black and orange.
When I export my file to .obj and open it in different software I see only grey dice.

What I am doing wrong?

This is my .mtl file content:

```
newmtl Material.001
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl Material.002
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Even if I change the colors, the content does not change.

[Link to file .blend](https://www.sendspace.com/file/v0f0q1)
I am using 2.71

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file and specify your blender version, export options?

Comment: I have updated ma post- if you need something just give me sign.

Comment: You are using cycles materials. .mtl only supports very simple materials. Basically you get the diffuse / specular / ambient colors of solid viewport shading.